# Is sum of numbered balls a multiple of a number?

Tags: combinatorics

would you please help me with this problem?

We have an urn with n balls numbered such that $X_i$ is the value of the ith ball, and we're asked to draw $k$ balls from the urn and then prove that their sum can be a multiple of $n$. Working on this problem, the furthest I got to is expecting the sum of the chosen balls which is $S= k (n+1) /2$ but I have no idea how to prove that we can obtain a multiple of $n$ by drawing some $k$ balls.

Any help please? Thanks

Comment: Pigeonhole principle, I think.

Comment: is $X_i$ a number from $1$ to $n$? Are balls distinctly numbered? And finally, their sum "can" or "must" be a multiple of $n$?

Comment: @sku $X_i$ can be any integer.  Numbers needn't be distinct.  Show that there is some subset of the balls whose labels sum to a multiple of $n$.

Comment: @sku we're just told that $X_i$ is a positive integer, so it can be anything and they don't need to be distinct I guess. We're asked to prove that it must be possible to take some balls and have their sum be a multiple of $n$, so "can".

Comment: We also have this hint: Think of $n$ bins labelled 0, 1, 2, . . . $n-1$ and then put each of the $n$ sums $x_1$, $x_1 + x_2$, . . . , $x_1 + · · · + x_n$ into the bin labelled with its remainder after division by $n$. But this only confuses me more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you don't know the numbers written on the balls, you can still solve the problem by counting:

- When you divide a number $m$ by $n$, the remainder can be anything in the list $0,1,2,\ldots, (n-1)$. If the remainder is 0, then $m$ is a multiple of $n$.
- Consider the sums you can make by adding up the values of the first few balls in order: $X_1$, $X_1+X_2$, $X_1+X_2+X_3$, and so on. Let $S_k$ be the sum of the first $k$ balls.
- We're considering $n$ different sums $S_1, \ldots, S_n$.
- When we divide those sums by $n$, we'll get $n$ remainders in the range $0\ldots (n-1)$.  If one of those remainders is zero, our proof is finished.
- Otherwise, all of the remainders are in the range $1,2,3,\ldots, (n-1)$, leaving zero out.  So by the pigeonhole principle, there are $n$ remainders chosen from the range of $n-1$ different numbers: $1,2,3,\ldots,(n-1)$. So two of these sums have the *same* remainder.
- Because two of them have the same remainder, $S_i$ and $S_j$, their difference is a multiple of $n$. (You can prove this because if $S_i = an + c$ and $S_j = bn+c$, then $S_i-S_j = (a-b)n$.)
- Their difference is $(X_1+\ldots+X_i) - (X_1+\ldots+X_j) = (X_{j+1}\ldots X_i).$  So this is a subset of balls that adds up to a multiple of $n$.

Comment: @CiaPan Oops, yes. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Consider the sums $$S_k = \sum_{i=1}^k{X_i}.$$  Apply the pigeonhole principle.

EDIT:

I see you've added a comment that you already had this hint.  Okay, since we are only concerned with divisibility by $n,$ only the remainder on division by $n$ matters.  If one of these sums leaves a remainder of $0,$ we're done, so the only possible remainders are $1,2,3,\dots,n-1.$

Now the pigeonhole principle tells you that two of the sums have the same remainder.  Can you finish it?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the subsets $\{X_1\}, \{X_1, X_2\}, ... \{X_1, X_2, .. X_n\}$
We have $n$ sets. Either one of them will be a multiple or some two will have the same remainder mod $n$

Hence their difference is $0 \ mod\  n$. If the sets are from $X_1$ to $X_k$ and $X_1$ to $X_m$, then the set $X_{k+1}$ to $X_m$ will have a sum that is a multiple of $n$.